# Мне выдаёт проблему "IndexError: string index out of range". В чём проблема?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот это код:

```
perviy = input("Введите слово: ")
vtoroy = input("Введите слово: ")
tretiy = input("Введите слово: ")
i = 1
slovo = str(None)
while i <= len(perviy):
    if perviy[i] == vtoroy[i]:
        slovo = slovo + perviy[i]
    else:
        if perviy[i] == tretiy[i]:
            slovo = slovo + perviy[i]
        else:
            if vtoroy[i] == tretiy[i]:
                slovo = slovo + vtoroy[i]
            else:
                print("IMPOSSIBLE")
                exit
    i += 1    
print(slovo)
```

Выдаёт ошибку `"IndexError: string index out of range"`. В чём проблема?

Смысл программы в том, чтобы понимать, что за слово было изначально. Например:

```
Ввод:              
Printen
Plinter
Primter

Вывод:
Printer
```

Comment: Вспомнил, что если не получается, то прога выдаёт "Impossible"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

индексация начинается с нуля поэтому надо писать `i = 0` а не `1`

место

```
while i <= len(perviy):
```

надо

```
while i < len(perviy):
```

и лучше использовать цикл `for`

```
for i in range(len(perviy)):
```

и можно будет убрать строки `i = 0` и `i += 1`

Answer (score 1):

У вас нету ввода первого слова, плюс к этому ошибка указывает на то, что вы хотите обратится к не действительному  элементу массива

```
perviy = input("Введите слово:")
vtoroy = input("Введите слово: ")
tretiy = input("Введите слово: ")
i = 0
slovo = str(None)
while i <= len(perviy) - 1:
    if perviy[i] == vtoroy[i]:
        slovo = slovo + perviy[i]
    else:
        if perviy[i] == tretiy[i]:
            slovo = slovo + perviy[i]
        else:
            if vtoroy[i] == tretiy[i]:
                slovo = slovo + vtoroy[i]
            else:
                print("IMPOSSIBLE")
                exit
    i += 1    
print(slovo)
```